# How did the Council of Ricks find the Rick they suspected for the murders?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In *Close Rick-Counters of the Rick Kind* the Council of Ricks sends a group of Ricks to pick up The One True Rick (to make things easier) suspecting him of the murders of other Ricks because he is well known for being against the idea of the Council

Now i figure that the designations they use when talking about one another is their origin dimension and given the purpose of a Morty if the council wanted to find a Rick they would go to his origin dimension that matched his designation.

But The One True Rick and his Morty aren't from the dimension they were picked up in by the council. they came from another which The One True Rick more or less destroyed humanity and came to the one they are in now being a dimension where the local Rick did find a way to restore humanity but was later blown up and killed with Morty after screwing something on the device he was working on. Morty even pointed out his grave to Summer and told her who he really was in *Rixty Minutes*

So then how did the Council of Ricks find them?

Comment: Wasn't it the "rick-eist rick"? Only morty was called the one true

Comment: @DarkHeart: If I'm not mistaken, "our" Rick and Morty described themselves as "the Rickiest Rick" and "the Mortiest Morty" (but it's likely that other Ricks and Morties have called themselves that too). "The One True Morty", as I understand it, is only mentioned in a pamphlet that is distributed at the Council of Ricks. This could be figurative (similar to how Christians live by the example of Jesus) or prophecy (one of the Morties is the One True Morty, similar to Neo being The One in the Matrix), but I don't remember any definitive proof that our Morty is the One True Morty.

Answer (score 4):

- When Rick and Morty jump from the Cronenberg dimension to the post-Cronenberg dimension, Rick specifically mentions that he jumped to a dimension that is *nearly identical* to the Cronenberg dimension (and that there are only a handful left). It stands to reason that Rick picked a similar dimension to make the transition easier.
- As the first episode of season 2 proves; a dimension gets separated into two dimensions when they receive different outcomes. E.g. if we are in "OurDimension" and flip a coin, we will be split off into two dimensions : "OurDimension-Heads" and "OurDimension-Tails".
- This also means that any similarities between two dimensions, took place **while the dimensions were still one and the same**

Continuing the "OurDimension" example, we now have two dimensions. But "Tails" me and "Heads" me both think back on what we did hours **before the coin flip**, that memory will be the same. Because at the time, there was only one "OurDimension".

Given that Rick has chosen to jump to a dimension that is near-identical; means that these two dimensions have been one and the same for a majority of time.
Anything that happened before the two dimensions got separated, are therefore shared by both Ricks.

---

How do you know for certain that the Council was looking for "our" Rick, and not "post-Cronenberg-but-now-blown-up" Rick? Since both Ricks are near identical as to their past; is there really a difference between them? They will both have been a pain in the ass to the Council.

Does the council of Ricks even care?

Since our Rick is morally okay with jumping between dimensions; it stands to reason that **all** Ricks are okay with it (or at the very least acknowledge that it's commonly accepted by Ricks).
So the council may be acting on the principle that **when you move dimensions, you take on that Rick's identity and responsibilities**.

Maybe this is a matter of indifference (arresting the man holding the smoking gun and not looking further), maybe it's a willful measure to prevent any Rick from claiming he does not originate from this universe and should not be held accountable.

Because in that case, every Rick could claim that for everything they are arrested for.

---

Rick and Morty's way of explaining the ways of the universe and its dimensions usually creates more questions than it answers. Which is something that Rick addresses in the pilot episode: **Don't think about it**.